# Why does my insertion sort Algorithm return out of order

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, insertion-sort, insertion

I am working on creating a basic insertion sort algorithm using Python.

My textbook shows the psudeocode of an insertion sort algorithm [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0gQaz.png).

If I follow that convention using python 3, I produce the following code:

```
def insertionSort(arr):
#Traverse through 1 to len array
   for j in range(1, len(arr)):
       key = arr[j]
       i = j-1
       while i >0 and arr[i] > key:  #this line seems incorrect?
           arr[i+1] = arr[i]
           i = i-1
       arr[i+1] = key
   return arr
```

If I set
arr = [12,11,13,5,6]
The result returns as [12,5,6,11,12,13] which obviously is not a correct sort.

After tweaking with the algorithm for some time changing the line I marked as incorrect to `while i>=0 and arr[i] > key:`
the algorithm gives the correct output. Is my book incorrect in omitting the equal sign or am I not understanding how the psuedocode operates within my textbook?

Comment: It looks like your correction is right; and if your book omitted the `=`, it is wrong.

Comment: @khelwood, look at the screenshot. The book is using a 1-based indexing. Both are right.

Comment: @bourbaki4481472 Yes, I saw your answer. Very perceptive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you mostly correctly translated the book's algorithm into Python. As you see, the book's algorithm is 1-based while Python is 0-based.

The book's algorithm starts at index 2 but you have to start at index 1.

This also translates to keeping the while loop going until the first index. In the book's case, that's 1 and in your case it should be 0 in Python. So the book is correct but you are also correct (because of the differences in indexing conventions).

Answer (score 1):

```py
def insertionSort(arr):
#Traverse through 1 to len array
   for j in range(1, len(arr)):
       key = arr[j]
       i = j-1
       # you need to change here to i>=0
       while i >= 0 and arr[i] > key:  #this line seems incorrect?
           arr[i+1] = arr[i]
           i = i-1
       arr[i+1] = key
   return arr
```